# Nginx how to match a dynamic location

Tags: reactjs, nginx, react-router, nginx-location, nginx-config

I have a nginx config file with a server context and multiple location contexts. How can I get the `/` in one of the location contexts to match a route that is dynamically generated? It's dynamically generated because my application connects to an api which returns `/number?somelongquerystring` which I concat with my existing route using javascript. This isn't a real directory, its simply used for [React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/) to display different data from the api using [React](https://reactjs.org/).

When I hard code the route it works fine.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost2;

        # more location contexts ...

        location /user/1231375741 { # My route
            proxy_pass http://litphum;
        }
    }
```

Would show something like
`http://localhost2/user/1231375741?access_token=BQDY6N-6RKgsE-c0Op8Q_neX02q_dnVixn_biBKJg_JOZH5C`

The `/1231375741` in this implementation is whats dynamically generated as well as the query string after it that is displayed in the url. The route will always begin with `/user` so I tried using RegEx to make this work with the help of [nginx's docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost2;

        # more location contexts ...

        location ~* ^/user/[a-zA-z\d]* {
            proxy_pass http://litphum;
        }
    }
```

I've tried the `.*` regex too but no luck. If the whole config file would help here it is.

```
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost2;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://litphum;
        }
        location /login {
            proxy_pass http://litphum-backend:8888/login;
        }
        location /callback {
            proxy_pass http://litphum-backend:8888/callback;
        }
        location ~* ^/user/[a-zA-z\d]* {
            proxy_pass http://litphum;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Something like [Docker with react-router and Nginx](https://mherman.org/blog/dockerizing-a-react-app/#react-router-and-nginx) might help you

Comment: This led me to my solution so thanks @Japsz